# how to get syscall document in systemtap

Tags: systemtap

I read the [document](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/documentation.html)
find about probe、function document 
[image]

and the usage:

```
man -k  probe::
```

probe::ioblock.end [probe::ioblock] (3stap)  - Fires whenever a block I/O transfer is complete
probe::ioblock.request [probe::ioblock] (3stap)  - Fires whenever making a generic block I/O request

**but how get the syscall  doucment from man** 
example :`syscall.write` document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't individual man pages about the syscalls.  See instead the **SYSCALL** section of `man stapprobes`.